# jquery validation - validate an array length

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I need to use jquery validation plugin and check the length of an array. If the length exceeds a maximum threshold value, I need to show a message below a textarea control.

The array is created using the values entered by the user in a textarea.

I am trying to follow this example: https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/ and started writing methods as shown below,

```
var names = GetNameList(); //returns the names entered in textarea in array format.

jQuery.validator.addMethod("NameCount", function(value, element) {
  return names.length <= 10;
}, "More than 10 names is not allowed");
```

But, I am wondering, is there any better approach or built in methods available in jquery validation plugin to validate the length of an array?

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not simply look at the [source code of the plugin](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/jquery.validate.js) and [the additional-methods file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.17.0/dist/additional-methods.js), or [read the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/), and see for yourself?  Otherwise, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: @Sparky, the link to the additional-methods file is helpful. Thanks.